# What is the WCF service moniker for this configuration?

Tags: vba, wcf, wsdl, app-config, moniker

I have the following app configuration file using my ip as a baseAddress:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="HelloServiceExample.HelloService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior">
        <endpoint
          address="HelloService"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="HelloServiceExample.IHelloService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint
          address="mex"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange">
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://{IP-ADDRESS}:{PORT}/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I have written a corresponding wsdl-based moniker string in VBA:

```
wsdlMonikerString = _
        "service4:address='http://{IP-ADDRESS}:{PORT}/HelloService.svc' " & _
        ", binding=BasicHttpBinding_IHelloService" & _
        ", bindingNamespace='http://tempuri.org/'" & _
        ", wsdl='" & wsdlText & "'" & _
        ", contract=IHelloService" & _
        ", contractNamespace='http://tempuri.org/'"
```

Where wsdlText is the string respresentation of the wsdl service. Gotten from http://{IP-ADDRESS}:{PORT}/?singleWsdl. But it does not seem to work, and I can't figure out why. I always get the error:

```
Run-time error '-2147221020 (800401e4)':

Automation error
Invalid syntax
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? What is a *wsdl moniker string*? It sounds painful

Comment: Realized the problem...I think. I'm using a Windows Service. This only works in IIS hosted Services.